# only "partial" autocomplete in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I'm using Eclipe Juno (Version: 4.2.1, Build id: M20120914-1800) and for some reason the Alt+/ autocomplete of variable/function names is not working properly - it completes the typed prefix to the last variable that matches the prefix without cycling through other options as used to be in previous versions.

I'm writing a python code and using pydev so for example, having the following lines:

```
var1 = 0
var2  = 1
var14444444444 = -1
```

then typing:

```
va
```

then hitting the Alt+/ combo will complete the 'va' to var14444444444. 
keeping the Alt pressed and pressing the / key again (and again) will do nothing as the editor  thinks that var14444444444 is the prefix to complete so no match is found.

In case I have the code:

```
var1 = 0
var14444444444XXXXXXX = -1
var2  = 1
var14444444444 = -1
```

typing

```
va
```

then Alt+/ yields completion to var14444444444 and keeping the Alt pressed and hitting the / again will autocomplete to var14444444444XXXXXXX.

This behavior is very annoying and inconsistent with previous versions. Is there a way to configure it? (I looked under the editor options but couldn't find anything)

I'll just add that the Ctrl+space does open a drop-down with all possible completions but this requires too many key strokes (Ctrl+space, + a sequence of arrows to get to the preferred completion, then Enter) which defeats the productivity purpose.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

1. Eclipse Preferences
2. PyDev
3. Editor
4. Code Completion
5. Check "**Request completion on all letters chars and _?**"

***Restart Eclipse.***